# What should be the datatype for the concatenated string in XSD?

Tags: wcf, xsd-validation

the server is returning cancel number as : **123459-3216-34579**
In XSD I tried to validate this cancelNumber as :

```
type="xs:string"
```

in wcf
the cancelNumber dataMember is of type string.

When I tried to validate this with xsd.
The XSd is not matching.It is throwing exception that it is expecting list of something.
I have map it only to string.

Please suggest something. I'm a newbie in XSD please bear if question is not clear and tell in comments?

Answer (score 0):

There was a error in the way I was creating XSD.
I needed to create a new file via Visual studio tool and which referred to that xsd via **ref** element